# error syntax ( execute psql query from shell script )

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

i got this query want to to be executed remotely on my 2nd server and

```
#!/bin/bash
QUERY=`psql -h my2ndserverip  -d testdb -U testuser  'select count(*) as result   
from testdb.user  where last_logged_date > (clock_timestamp()  -interval '90    minutes)
 echo "users = $QUERY" > tmp.txt
```

any tips to fix syntax ?

Comment: not sure if its the only quotes

Comment: Sure, but that would be an **EXCELLENT** start.

Comment: great , can you point to me where i missed quotes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a here document (heredocuments preserve quotes AND allow shell-variable subtitution, as illustrated by the parameter `90` which is used **inside single quotes**):

```
#!/bin/bash

limit=${1:-90}

psql -h my2ndserverip  -d testdb -U testuser -t -A <<EOFEOF > tmp.txt
  SELECT count(*) AS result   
  FROM "user"  
  WHERE last_logged_date > clock_timestamp()-interval '${limit} minutes'
  ;
EOFEOF

exitcode=$?
result=`cat tmp.txt`

echo "Limit=${limit} Exitcode=${exitcode} Result=${result}"
#Eof
```

I suppose you want psql to omit the column headers etc, so I added the `-t -A` flags to the psql commandline.

BTW I changed `from testdb.user`, to `FROM user`, I don't think you have a schema named 'testdb'.

Answer (score 0):

there are more than one issue

instead quotes in SQL query, you can use $$

```
postgres=# select interval $$90 min$$;
 interval 
──────────
 01:30:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: but am running my query in shell script , and out put echo to a file

Comment: yes, I know, and your problem is in badly used nested quotes. So, use $$ instead nested quotes. 'SELECT .. interval '90 ... missing ' missing second ' .. ---> 'SELECT interval $$90 minutes$$'